# Variable Timestepping & Unexpected Jerkiness/Stutter in a Simple Test Case Scenario

Tags: c++, game-loop, timestep, deltatime

I have been bashing my head of an extremely simple case in my C++ game and would like some help. I have been researching about game loops, variable & fixed timestepping, rendering interpolation, vsync. etc all your classic devils and I do not seem to understand one simple problem.

Assume an extremely simple case:

**Variable-rate loop:**

```
calculateDelta();
myObject.position += _constant * g_deltaTime;
renderGame();
```

**Scene:** 1 unlit cube moving horizontally, fixed camera.

**Hardware & Rendering:** VSYNC off, Rendering 4K (3840x2160) framebuffer, 60Hz refresh monitor, Intel UHD 630 integrated graphics.

**Stats:** Around 35~ FPS, delta oscilliating around 0.025 - 0.033, running delta average (smoothed) somewhat stable around 0.026-0.029

**Result**: Pretty jerky motion, not smooth at all.

Now I know this already smells bad, and I read all about why we should use: fixed-time-stepping for physics, accumulations, interpolation for leftovers etc. etc.

I am aware of all that, but this is not a question regarding "what is better". This is a question about this: When I ran the exact same test case with same hardware on builds taken from Unreal and Unity, I get similar results 30+ FPS, but the motion is **really smooth**. I mean of course it's not awesome, considering it's just 30 FPS something struggling, but 10x better than what I get on my own engine.

Now you might say yeah ofc. Unity and Unreal's loop ain't like the one you have given above. But I ran the test case (moving the cube) on Actor::ReceiveTick() and Update() functions respectively, which are code paths that only receive **variable delta time**, without any **substepping, fixed update catch up etc.**. I am pretty sure this is the case, as I even debugged UE4 source code & verified this is the code path :

```
TonOfInit();
WinMain Loop
   EngineTick() -> TonOfTicks() -> CalculateDelta() -> WorldTick() -> ........ -> ActorTick()
```

So I am pretty sure my code has pretty similar code-path in regards to moving the object by constant * deltaTime units. Now **what do these engines do that produce the smooth results?**

Couple things came to my mind:

**Delta Magic**: At least looking at UE source code, they smooth out and cap the delta time, sleep if necessary etc. prior to ticking the world. I am pretty sure Unity does some magic as well, however simply "manipulating dt for better experience" would not create such a big difference in smoothing the motion?

**Interpolating?**: Yeah both engines run fixed-timesteps for physics, and I am pretty sure there is some sort of interpolation magic going on, but I would expect this to only be true for those transforms being updated in physics? e.g. PhysicsActors and Rigidbodies. If you are simply and "visually" moving a cube with variable-frame-rate, how would the interpolation even work under the hood, what would be the alpha?

**OS/Window Setup**: Edge case but yeah, I have also looked into the issues of windowed vs full-screen modes, Windows application priority levels etc. Seems like my app has all the correct setup and nothing should create such a big difference.

**My rendering is broken**: Thought of this too, simplified my renderer as much as I can. (It was a multi-threaded Vulkan renderer with double-buffering frames, now its 1 frame-in-flight, single threaded, no fancy descriptors, simple push-constants for matrices etc. as simple as possible). That wasn't enough, tried some basic "example Vulkan apps" from github repos here and there, same problem and jittery motion.

So yeah, bit of a long one but, what do these engines might be doing to ensure smooth motion even though the user is moving the objects in Tick()/Update() e.g. variable-frame-rate? I am aware we are talking AAA quality systems here and of course they will be better than what I am doing, but I can't understand the "concept". I feel like there ain't any solution to this jerky motion, but they seem to be finding one?

Note: Additionally ofc. I have eliminated debug/development build difference possibilities etc, also I am sure that the environment & hardware is the same on the engine builds (forcing Vsync off and forcing Intel UHD 630 etc.) I can't provide here gifs because well, 4K recording + converting to gif kills the whole point of understanding the difference.

**Edit**: Additional information regarding my game loop:

Frames, Delta Time, Object Position Line Chart: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtQPf.jpg

WinMain:

```
Application* app = PluginEntry_CreateApp();
while(!app->ExitRequested())
    app->Tick();
app->Shutdown();
```

Application::Tick()

```
// Basic delta-time
// PlatformTime uses QueryPerformanceCounter() for calculating CPU ticks
// GetDeltaSeconds64() simply multiplies the tick difference with secondsPerCycle retrieved from QueryPerformanceFrequency()
static uint64 previous     = PlatformTime::GetCycles64();
const uint64  current      = PlatformTime::GetCycles64();
double        deltaSeconds = PlatformTime::GetDeltaSeconds64(previous, current, 1.0);
previous                   = current;

// Disabled for the test, handles delta-time smoothness, sleep-if-configured & required etc. 
// For the test everything is unbound, update & render as fast as possible
// CorrectDeltaTime();

m_engine.GetInput().PreTick();
PlatformProcess::PumpMessages();

// Yield-CPU check.
if (!SystemInfo::GetAppHasFocus())
    PlatformProcess::Sleep(.1);

m_engine.Tick(SystemInfo::GetDeltaTimeF()); 
SystemInfo::SetFrames(SystemInfo::GetFrames() + 1);
```

Engine::Tick(float dt)

```
m_input.Tick(dt);
m_gfxManager.Tick(dt);

// omitting other unrelated ticks

// Gets currently installed world, ticks, which results in game code being ticked and object position being incremented.
m_levelManager.Tick(dt);

// Immediate rendering for the purposes of the test.
m_gfxManager.Render();
```

GfxManager::Render();

```
// Vulkan details are hidden,  but basically

ResetAndWaitForFences();
uint32 img = AcquireImage();
RecordCommandBuffers(frameIndex, img);
SubmitGraphicsQueue();
PresentGraphicsQueue();
```

Comment: Vulcan on Intel integrated graphics, will not match the performance of OpenGL or DX.  The driver, in past releases, only provided a compatibility layer, not native support. This support is improving per release. Try updating the drivers.